# Hyperlink + click like button on NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a username variable and a message string such as "liked your post" and in order to be able to cast it as one string, I combined them in an NSMutableAttributedString. As it'll be easy, I am

```
let username = notification["username"].string
let notificationBody = notification["body"].string

let notificationString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(username!) \(notificationBody!)")
notificationString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()], range: NSMakeRange(0, (username?.characters.count)!))
cell.notificationLabel.attributedText = notificationString
```

Colouring the text is working as expected, however, I want to be able to click on the username and at the same time achieve a colour-effect of click (like click on button). Here is what I mean:

Without click: [image]

on click : 
[image] and segue to another VC.

---

I actually achieved what I want to achieve with a primitive hack that I absolutely do not like. What I did was, first I added an extra button over username and set background-color: clear color. And it visually seems nice if the width of the username coincidentally matches the width of the button in Storyboard - cell. Otherwise, it seems buggy.

Extra Button layer over 'username' text: [image]

---

What is the practical way of achieving what I want to achieve? Should I just change the width of the transparent button for each cell, according to the username character count? So if for 4-6 words, x width; if 8-10 words, y width?

Are there any better ways than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the layout to have a button that contains the user name and a label that contains the body instead of just one label. That way the button will always be the same size as the username.

Comment: And add constraint between username button & label? Is there a way to add this button/click feature to NSAttributedText instead?

Comment: Yes. From your image I couldn't tell if you were using autolayout.

Comment: Nope, I am not. I just dragged it over username

Comment: Auto layout is definitely the easiest way to do it. Otherwise you would have to make a gesture recognizer that find what characters you tapped on and perform an action if the characters are in the username.